# "An error occurred please retry your request" not undoing upvote

Tags: bug, voting, user-interface

Attempting to upvote an answer, I got the "An error occurred please retry your request" message. This didn't undo the upvote in the UI, however, even though the vote never went through. The behavior should be removal of the upvote like when you attempt to upvote your own post.

Comment: and what if you refresh and try again?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That worked and I was able to cast my upvote (it had not been cast when I received the error). This is more about error handling behavior.